# Unable to deploy Builds using v0.19.1

Tags: multiversx

Any contract I successfully build that has a dependency to elrond-wasm 0.19.1 fails to deploy

[image: Transaction details - invalid contract code]

**Is there any known issue regarding this or am I the only one facing this?**
Trying to build on the older 0.18.2 works but a lot of the contract code has to be changed in order to achieve a build.

Most examples I have tried to build and deploy from the Elrond Github Rust examples repository fail when deployed with the same error.

Although the one found at https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/ping-pong-smart-contract that is using these dependencies:

```
[dependencies.elrond-wasm]
version = "0.18.2"
features = ["derive"]

[dependencies.elrond-wasm-node]
version = "0.18.2"
optional = true

[dev-dependencies.elrond-wasm-debug]
version = "0.18.2"
```

works great. Build and deploy work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to deploy on the devnet this will fail because it hasn't been updated to 0.19 yet, so you still have to use 0.18.x there.

Also note that 0.19.1 wasn't officially released yet, so that will most likely fail on mainnet and devnet as well.

So either way the solution as you have already described is to downgrade your elrond-wasm versions to 0.19.0 or 0.18.2, depending on the net on which you want to deploy.

Comment: Do you have a link where the versions used on the different environments is displayed? I'm also curious if I could maybe use 0.19.x on the testnet.

Comment: Unfortunately I think there is no such list right now.
But it should be the following for now:

Devnet: 0.18.2

Testnet: 0.19.0

Mainnet: 0.19.0

Of course all versions lower than the one specified should also work.

So you should be able to use 0.19.0 on the testnet. Not sure if 0.19.1 will work though, because like I said, it isn't officially released yet.

Comment: Please use the devnet for testing and development purposes. It's more stable in time, more similar with the mainnet and it has additional developer tools.